# REST_API PHP Post with Raw Parameter

Tags: php, rest, api, post, parameters

Why I get null result when I submit. How to post with raw param?

Here's my method for the request:

```
$urlsp = "https://xxx/xxx/forgotpassword/xxx";
$header = array("X-Application-Token : 123er", "Content-Type : application/json");
$param = array("account: 080000xxx",
            "secretQuestion:",
            "secretAnswer:",
            "newPassword: .md5($pass).",
            "issuer: 567800");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlsp);
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$json_data = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

$data = json_decode($json_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your param to be like this:

```
$param = array('account'=> '080000xxx','secretQuestion' => $question,'secretAnswer' => $answer,'newPassword' => md5($pass),'issuer' => '567800');
```